# SharePoint list customization

Tags: development, custom-list, list-form

I would like to build a SharePoint list, which will be a list of forms.  Each form will have an effective date range. I have a list of 100 documents and the each document has an effective date range. For example, document 12345 is effective between 01/01/18 and 12/31/2018. Id like a person viewing the list to be able to pick a date and filter to a list of documents that were active on the date they selected. In this case if they selected today it would be in the view, but if they selected 01/01/17 as the "as of date" it would not be in the view.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes this question has received. The essence of the question is having list items with a property for dates (resulting into a date range), which can be used to filter the list's content. Not that hard to understand, eh?

Comment: I'll answer it when it re-opens. It can be done oob without development.

Comment: OK thanks. Im brand new to this site so Im note sure why my question was closed, but hopefully it makes more sense now.